# How to pass data to any component irrespective of child-parent in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to pass data to a component, but i am getting error.

```
Property 'doSomethingX' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.ngtsc(2339)
app.component.ts(5, 12): Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Here what i did.

**What I want to achieve:**
I'm developing an app/website in which if the user does not log in, a popup should appear directing the user to the log-in screen. **requireloginregister** is a component where user will be directed to. Now I want to make this component active/visible if someone clicks on a feature that requires authentication.

**What I did:**

In a component, to add the item to wish list, user must login/register first. So when user click on the wish item button, first i am checking if user is logged in or not. If not logged-in i am sending signal to **requireloginregister** component to become visible.

```
  @Output() public eventName = new EventEmitter();
  this.eventName.emit(true); // "true" is signal
```

and on **requireloginregister** component i am receiving this signal as

```
<app-requireloginregister (eventName)="doSomethingX($event)" ></app-requireloginregister>
```

Inside **requireloginregister** component:

```
doSomethingX(e)
{
alert("Signal received" + e);
}
```

**Where problem occurs:**

The problem occurs when i add html template to a**pp.component.html** file

```
<app-abovenav></app-abovenav>
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer> 
<app-requireloginregister (eventName)="doSomethingX($event)" ></app-requireloginregister>
```

The reason I want to pass data without child/parent relationship is that, there are many components in my application which first check if user is not logged in, all of these components will have to pass a signal to **requireloginregister** component.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Use the service communication pattern](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)

Comment: `Property 'doSomethingX' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'` You get this error because `doSomethingX` is not a property of `AppComponent`. If you define a method with that name inside the component, the error goes away.

Comment: Yes, I did that. The error in fact goes away. However, for me it does not make any scene if doSomethingX is an attribute of requireloginregister component, shouldn't doSomethingX() exists inside requireloginregister component. Also, define the method inside requireloginregister component but it keep saying "does not exists on type AppComponent" doSomethingX() is no good to me if i declare this in AppComponent

Comment: Thank you @Liam for direction. My issue solve by using the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my issue resolved. If anyone else having this communication type of issue, follow below steps.
[image: What can you do with service in angular]
Credits [Simplilearn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v1mQB4BCIo)

**Step 01:**

Create a service using

> ng g service "your-service-name"

**Step 02:**

In your service.ts file get the instance of the component that you want to send signal to. In my case, component name was requireloginregister

```
import {RequireloginregisterComponent} from "../app/components/requireloginregister/requireloginregister.component";
```

Then I create an instance of RequireloginregisterComponent in my service class.

```
  r = new RequireloginregisterComponent();
```

Now I have the reference, I can call any public method defined inside **RequireloginregisterComponent** class.

**Last Step:**

**Component from where you want to send the signal.**
Simply import your service inside your component. In my case, I called my service as "InvokerService" so

```
import { InvokerService } from './../../invoker.service';
```

Now define your service inside constructor as well

```
constructor( private invokerService:InvokerService) { }
```

use invokerService variable to call method inside your service, which is linked to your other component, you want to pass signal to.

**RequireloginregisterComponent**

> I want to send data/signal to this class/component

```
import { Component, OnInit   } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-requireloginregister',
  templateUrl: './requireloginregister.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./requireloginregister.component.css']
})
export class RequireloginregisterComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
  message(message:any)
  { 

  alert("Message Received: " + message;)
  
  }
  
 
}
```

**My Service class**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {RequireloginregisterComponent} from "../app/components/requireloginregister/requireloginregister.component";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InvokerService {

  constructor() { }
  r = new RequireloginregisterComponent();
  
  messageTranspoter(msg:any){ 
    this.r.message(msg);
  }
}
```

**I am sending data/signal from this component/class**

```
import { InvokerService } from './../../invoker.service';
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-productdetail',
  templateUrl: './productdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productdetail.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ProductdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private invokerService:InvokerService) { } 
   
  sendMessage(){
  
       this.invokerService.requireAuth();

   }
}
```